# SearchView with SherlockActivity returns null on getActionView()

Tags: java, android, actionbarsherlock

I've been transitioning an Android application developed with Eclipse over to Android Studio. It targets a minimum API level of 10 (current 22) and uses ActionBarSherlock (huge bummer). With Eclipse, it was making use of ActionBarSherlock 4.2 in a library project, but now it seems the only way to use ActionBarSherlock is with 4.4 as an AAR with gradle. `compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'`

After getting everything migrated, the app now crashes whenever the SearchView is used on Android 2.3.5 (works fine on Android 4). The problem is in onCreateOptionsMenu menu.findItem(R.id.search_menu_item).getActionView() which returns null. Here's what my SearchActivity class looks like:

```
public class SearchActivity extends SherlockActivity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.search_view);

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.search_view_list);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search_menu, menu);

        //Get the action view of the menu item whose id is search
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search_menu_item).getActionView();
        searchView.setQueryHint("Search for ISBN, UPC, EAN or Title");

        final Menu savedMenu = menu;

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                  //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), query, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  if (mOnlineSearchTask == null)
                  {
                      mOnlineSearchTask = new OnlineSearchTask(getBaseContext());
                      mOnlineSearchTask.execute(query, "title", "All");
                      ((SearchView) savedMenu.findItem(R.id.search_menu_item).getActionView()).clearFocus();
                  }

                  return true;
              }

              @Override
              public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                  return false;
                }
            }
        );

        searchView.setIconified(false);

        return true;
    }
}
```

search_view.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/search_view_list"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"

        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
    </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

search_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <item android:id="@+id/search_menu_item"
        android:title="Search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_inverse"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:actionViewClass="com.actionbarsherlock.widget.SearchView" />
</menu>
```

Comment: I have not moved to Gradle or Android Studio but have recently updated the Android SDK Tools/Platform-tools/Build-tools. I am now having the same null return from getActionView() for older (<= 2.3.7) devices.

Comment: I ended up just converting my whole app to use appcompat v7's ActiionBar support thing. It really wasn't too much work.

Comment: Reality is, Android 2.3 is pretty close to dead.

Comment: Sadly, it is still around 4% of our active users.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your xml file (search_menu.xml) to :

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <item android:id="@+id/search_menu_item"
        android:title="Search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_inverse"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        app:actionViewClass="com.actionbarsherlock.widget.SearchView" />
</menu>
```

It looks almost the same (because it's really similiar) - I changed the last line from `android:actionViewClass....` to `app:actionViewClass...`

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work. Had to add xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" at the top, but even then I get: "Error retrieving parent for item. No resource founfd that matches attribute 'actionViewClass' in package 'mypackage'." Seems hopeless since I'm targeting a minimum of API 10 (which if I'm not mistaken, is the whole point of actionbarsherlock). Project has been working for 3+ years in Eclipse.

Comment: Well, the SearchViews were implemented in API11, have you tried raising your minimum API level?

Comment: I must support 10. This exact code with the SearchView has worked fine before with 10. Not sure what my problem is.